# Should HTML Code Be All In Lower-Case

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, warnings

**EDIT:**

The answers are:

1. `zackzurn`'s answer.
2. `jrummell`'s comment under this question.

---

Visual Studio 2010 shows warnings when I use capital letters for HTML attributes. For example, this will cause 2 warnings because of capital letters in `cellPadding` and `bgColor`:

`<table cellPadding="1" bgColor="whitesmoke" >`

Warning:

`Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): This name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed.`

Google [HTML/CSS coding standard](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml) suggests that only lower-case letters should be used. But one can argue that capital letters sometimes improve readability of attributes.

While warnings are shown for the general HTML code, there are not warnings when capital letters are used inside ASP elements. This does not generate any warnings:

`<asp:label id="lblProvider" CssClass="normalLabel1" Font-Bold="True" Runat="server">Select       Provider Name:</asp:label>` .

**Question:**

1. Is it appropriate to use upper case letters to improve readability of your HTML code or you should use only lower-case letters?
2. Why this warning is not shown for `<asp: ... >` elements?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `<asp: ... >` are rendered as normal html tags on the client, so the browser never sees them.

Comment: For XHTML, the answer is trivial. For HTML in general, the question is an opinion poll, not constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the page from the XHTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2

Quoted below:

> XHTML documents must use lower case for all HTML element and attribute
>   names. This difference is necessary because XML is case-sensitive e.g.
>   <li> and <LI> are different tags.

With regard the ASP tag not throwing errors as far as I know those tags are used by Visual Studio to generate compliant XHTML and are not the final elements that will show up in the HTML.

Comment: XML, good point. Did not think about that. And what about ASP elements? Why they can use upper case letters?

Comment: Try it out and view the source on your final html output I am pretty sure everything will be made lowercase. As far as I can tell they do not enforce capitalization rules on their tags for readability. The XML used to define ASP elements can be however Visual Studio wants it to be as long as the final output is valid.

Comment: Nice personal site BTW.

Comment: Thank you. Glad to help (Even though I've never used ASP a day in my life). :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

If your doctype is `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` you MUST use lowercase characters to get it through the validator.

If you decide to go with any HTML doctype, you can have uppercase characters in your attributes.

Comment: Or any other XHTML doctype, not just transitional.